# Cannot get images to upload to wp/v2/media with React Native

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

I've been all over here and https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/ and https://wordpress.org/ and cannot find anyone talking about this. I can get it working using postman and selecting the file, however i cannot get it work submitting it as either "multipart/form" or "image/png".

I also cannot find anything detailing exactly how the request should look. I can create attachments but they're empty images of the correct size using base64 data as the post body. I feel like I'm missing something simple but cannot figure out what it is. I'm using postman to abstract out other distractions, my headers are:

```
POST /wp-json/wp/v2/media
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=image_1.png
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Bearer {JWT_Auth_token}
```

body is just

```
{
    data:image/png;base64,{base64_string_here}
}
```

I get a returned response like it created an attachment, but when I check in the wp admin it's an blank file, that appears to be the correct kb size but doesn't display. What am I missing???

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out! With the help of this WP Trac issue https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41774.

So my request looks like this now:

```
async function uploadImageAsync(urlbase, uri, base64, token) {
    let apiUrl = urlbase + '/wp-json/wp/v2/media';
    let formData = new FormData();

    //dynamically get file type
    let uriParts = uri.split('.');
    let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

    //generate some random number for the filename
    var randNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var randNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    formData.append('file', {
        base64,
        name: `photo-${randNumber1}-${randNumber2}.${fileType}`,
        type: `image/${fileType}`,
    });

    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token, 
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',           
        },
    };

    console.log('header options: ',options);
    console.log('form-data options: ',formData);

    return fetch(apiUrl, options);

}
```

When base64 comes in it's formatted simply as base64: {base64-string}. Not data:image/type, since that is specified in the form data. The other thing that's key here is setting the key of form to 'file'.

Comment: Can you give an example of the base64, that is the only bit I am a little unsure of. are you passing an object like so `{base64: b64stringencode}`, or is it simply `{b64stringencode}`

Answer (score 0):

The original answer did not work for me, so I changed "`uri: base64,`". now it's working fine

```
formData.append('file', {
        uri: base64,
        name: `photo-${randNumber1}-${randNumber2}.${fileType}`,
        type: `image/${fileType}`,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put my solution somewhere in case other people find it useful. I am using react-native and redux, this solution is an action within the redux framework.

```
export const uploadMedia = image => {
  return async function(dispatch, getState) {
    const { token } = getState();

    const uriParts = image.uri.split('.');
    const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
    const bodyFormData = new FormData();

    bodyFormData.append('file', {
      base64: image.base64,
      name: `photo-qa.${fileType}`,
      type: `image/${fileType}`
    });
    try {
      const request = await fetch(
        'http://stagingsite.test/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=__boundrytext__'
          },
          body: bodyFormData
        }
      );
      const response = await request.json();

      console.log({
        text: 'uploadMedia', response, request
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return ErrorHandler(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: props to @marshall-o I wouldnt have figured this out without his initial post