# How to transfer image with Wordpress REST API using Google Apps Script

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to upload images from Gmail email attachments to Wordpress with Google Apps Script, using Wordpress REST API.

I am successfully able to create the media file, but it is always blank so the actual image data is not actually transferring.

I was able to authenticate successfully, and the Wordpress credentials definitely have upload permissions. A media attachment is created in Wordpress when I run my code, but it is blank and not the actual image. I've tried sending the payload as a Blob, as a string Base64 encoded, as bytes, using getAs("image/jpeg") and many other ways of grabbing the file data.

```
uploadImage();

function getImage(){
  var email = GmailApp.search("subject:(EMAIL WITH IMAGE)")[0].getMessages[0];
  var attachment = email.getAttachments()[0];
  var blob = att.copyBlob();
  return blob;
}

function uploadImage(){

  // ... SUCCESSFUL AUTHENTICATION OCCURS

  var postPayload = {
    "file": getImage()
  }

  var params = {
    "payload": JSON.stringify(postPayload),
    "contentType": "image/jpeg",
    "method": "POST",
      "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                   "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=test.jpg"}
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://mydomainname.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/', params);
  return response
}
```

I receive a valid JSON response of the created attachment, and I would expect the image to upload to Wordpress. However, the attachment created is a blank/empty file and not the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getImage()` returns the blob of the image, how about this modification?

Please modify the object of `params` as follows. **Before you run the script, please confirm whether `att` of `att.copyBlob()` is `attachment`.**

#### From:

```
"payload": JSON.stringify(postPayload),
```

#### To:

```
"payload": getImage(),
```

- In this modification, `postPayload` is not used.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to use REST API of wordpress and your access token can be used.
- I think that `"payload": getImage()` can be used. But if an error occurs, please try to modify it to `"payload": getImage().getBytes()`.

If this was not the solution of your issue, I apologize. If an error occurs, please show the error message.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this worked but it did! I had read in many places that you need to send the payload to Wordpress API as a JSON in format `{ "file": theFile }`, but I guess I didn't actually need that. To be honest, I'm still not completely sure WHY your method works but it did. Thanks so much!

Comment: @farbo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In my experience, I had uploaded the images using curl command like `curl -X POST -H "content-disposition: attachment; filename=tmp" -H "Authorization: ###" -H "Content-Type: image/png" --data-binary "@image.png" "url"`. So I thought that this way might be able to be used for Google Apps Script. But, I’m not sure if this modification for Google Apps Script worked. So I'm glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getImage(){
  var email = GmailApp.search("subject:(EMAIL WITH IMAGE)")[0].getMessages[0];
  var attachment = email.getAttachments()[0];
  var blob = att.copyBlob();
  return 'data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately same problem -- a media attachment shows up in Wordpress but it is blank/empty.

Comment: Perhaps a security plugin is keeping files from being uploaded to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uploadImage();

function getImage(){
  var email = GmailApp.search("subject:(EMAIL WITH IMAGE)")[0].getMessages[0];
  var attachment = email.getAttachments()[0];
  var blob = att.copyBlob();
  return  Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
}

function uploadImage(){

  // ... SUCCESSFUL AUTHENTICATION OCCURS

  var postPayload = {
    "file": {
        uri: getImage(),
        name: 'filename',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
    }
  }

  var params = {
    "payload": JSON.stringify(postPayload),
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    "method": "POST",
      "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                   "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=test.jpg",
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                   'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'   
                  }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://mydomainname.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/', params);
  return response
}
```

I implemented in App script the solution given in this question [Cannot get images to upload to wp/v2/media with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993746/cannot-get-images-to-upload-to-wp-v2-media-with-react-native)

Comment: For some reason this solution does not work when I try, the media file in Wordpress is blank/empty and not actually an image.