# Wordpress says, "rest_upload_sideload_error" for a recognized type in an image upload from Google Apps Script. Why?

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, wordpress-rest-api

Context: uploading images to WordPress.

I've been digging around on this for a while. There are lots of StackOverflow postings about the issue, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263097/how-to-transfer-image-with-wordpress-rest-api-using-google-apps-script) from which I have derived the code below.

```js
function test3() {
    const png = DriveApp.getFileById('id of a png file');
    const parm = {};
    parm.method = "post";
    parm.headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode('user' + ':' + 'application password'),
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + "name of file.png",
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    };
    parm.payload = Utilities.base64Encode(png.getBlob().getBytes());
    parm.muteHttpExceptions = false;
    const x = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://client.domain/wp-json/wp/v2/media", parm);
    Logger.log(x.getContentText());
}
```

The response from this is

```
Exception: Request failed for https://client.domain returned code 500. 
Truncated server response: 
{"code":"rest_upload_sideload_error","message":"Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.","data":{"status":500}} 
(use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
test3   @ Tests.gs:15
```

One of the suggestions, at [Kinsta](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons/) suggesting installing the [WP Extra File Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/) plugin. No effect. Even selecting `Check only file extensions` had no effect (and 'png' is one of the standard accepted types.)

Where to now?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the "problem" was with [Sucuri](https://docs.sucuri.net/website-firewall/whitelist-and-blacklist/whitelist-an-ip-address/#whitelisting-ip-ranges) which needed to be told to whitelist googlecontent IP addresses, namely `107.178.0.0/16`. Once Sucuri stopped blocking the traffic, the image was uploaded.